# How to disable react button until Meteor Method finishes

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, meteor

I have a Meteor app with a react component that has a button that fires an async meteor method.

The method takes some time to run, and I wish to prevent it from being clicked again while waiting for the response. 
I can disable the button in the click handler, but once the function completes, I can't seem to re-enable it, since 'this' (being the react component) is unknown for the callback function.

Any ideas on how to modify a react element on a method callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, {useState} from "react"

const SampleAsync = () => {

  let [isWaiting, setWaiting ] = useState(false)

  let meteorMethod = () => {
      setWaiting(true)
      Meteor.call('insertSometing', data,(result,error) => {
        if(error) 
        console.log('erro')
        else
        setWaiting(false)
      })
  }


  // If isWaiting is true the button disable and if false unable
  // you can also do this: <button disable={isWaiting} onClick={meteorMethod}>Submit</button>
  return (
    <div>
      // you can add inline if
      <button disable={isWaiting == true ? true : false  } onClick={meteorMethod}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SampleAsync
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a boolean in your local state like `isWaiting: false` and in the function inside your event handler (your async meteor method), once that button has been clicked it should change the `isWaiting` value to `true`. And depending on what pattern you choose (async/await or promises) I would set `isWaiting` back to false on both success and reject. After that, have the `disable` attribute dependent on the `isWaiting` state.

You can use try-catch-finally:

```
const [isWaiting, setIsWaiting] = useState(false);

async function meteorMethod() {
  setIsWaiting(true)
  try {
    // await...
  } catch(err) {
    // ...
  }
  finally {
    setIsWaiting(false)
  }
}

return (
  <>
    <button disable={isWaiting} onClick={meteorMethod}>Submit</button>
  </>
)
```